# How to organize my API based on Laravel 5?

Tags: php, rest, laravel-5

I have usual resource UserController

```
UserController extends Controller {

   public function index() {  /**... some code */ }

   public function store(Request $request) {  /**... some code */ }

   public function show(User $user) {  /**... some code */ }

   public function update(Request $request, User $user) {  /**... some code */ }

   public function destroy(User $user) {  /**... some code */ }

}

User extends Model {
   protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'email'];
}
```

And I have a child resource ContactController

```
ContactController extends Controller {

   public function index(User $user) {  /**... some code */ }

   public function store(Request $request, User $user) {  /**... some code */ }

   public function show(User $user, Contact $contact) {  /**... some code */ }

   public function update(Request $request, User $user, Contact $contact) {  /**... some code */ }

   public function destroy(User $user, Contact $contact) {  /**... some code */ }

}

Contact extends Model {
   protected $fillable = [ 'phones', 'user_id' ];
}
```

In my routes.php

```
Route::apiResource('users', 'UserController');

Route::apiResource('users.contacts', 'ContactController');
```

In my case, I can create thought API only one contact for the user.
Make request to

***POST api/users/12/contacts***
After that, I can get this contact ***GET api/users/12/contacts/11***
And a client can create as many as possible contacts use ***POST api/users/12/contacts*** But my user can have only one contact.

Actual I can solve this by adding validation, but I think this trick is not solving the problem correctly

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question.  You want to restrict your user to only having 1 contact.  So we're talking about a one to one relationship?

Comment: @JohnHalsey Yep!

Comment: So did you put the relationships on the models?  If each model has a hasOne method on it relating to the other, it should resolve that.